# Jackson serializer wrapping lists by default?

Tags: java, json, xml, spring, jackson

I'm using `spring` with `RestTemplate` to `postForEntity(req, rsp)` xml to a webservice.

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer initJackson() {
    return (builder) -> builder.modules(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
}
```

The java bean is autogenerated from `xsd` files using `xsdtojava`. Thus I cannot modify the generated class!

Problem: The

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Generated
public class MyRequest {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private SubReq subs;

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType
    public static class SubReq {
        private List<String> list;
    }
}
```

Result: the `<list>` element contains additional nested `<list>` elements. But why? And how can I prevent?

Current:

```
<MyRequest>
    <SubReq>
        <list>  
            <list>val1</list>
            <list>val2</list>
        </list>
    </SubReq>
</MyRequest>
```

My goal:

```
<MyRequest>
    <SubReq>
        <list>val1</list>
        <list>val2</list>
    </SubReq>
</MyRequest>
```

How can I configure jackson to not wrap the lists inside?

The `MyRequest` element is autogenerated from:

```
<xs:schema>
    <xs:element name="MyRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SubReq">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="list" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    ...
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Did you try @JsonUnwrapped ?

Comment: As written, I cannot modify the autogenerated java classes. Thus, I cannot add any custom annotations. I somehow have to add a global configuration to unwrapp any `List` or `Map`.

Comment: ..and can't modify the objectmapper/deserializer attributes either?

Comment: Objectmapper is in my control. That would be possible. Or better let's say the `builder`, eg as written I add register the `JaxbAnnotationModule` explicit to tell jackson to make use of the JAXB properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by disabling unwrapper grobally with `defaultUseWrapper(false)`:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer initJackson() {
    return (builder) -> builder.modules(new JaxbAnnotationModule())
                    .defaultUseWrapper(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE) to true for this :

```
objectMapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

The default value of this attribute is `true`.

This is under a restriction that preferably I would have annotated such fields with `@JsonUnwrapped` while generating the code itself.

Comment: Hm, I tried setting both `UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS` and `UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` but that did not help. The lists are still nested. Well and as said, I cannot add `@JsonUnwrapped` to the autogenerated classes...

Comment: Sounds like a possible bug in that case, does this also happen for classes not declared as inner class and yet consist of a similar model?

Comment: So but the question is: is the autogenerated java class hierarchy wrong, or the deserialization feature? Added the `xsd` source above.

Comment: @membersound If the `UNWRAP..` feature works with classes that are **not inner classes** this would certainly be a bug. Haven't tested though, but my first thought is I have seen normal POJOs being feasibly used with @JsonUnwrapped as inner classes as well. In which case it could be possibly at deserialization level that things are messed up.